# Connect a MSSQL created database with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, macos, postgresql

I use Mac and PostgreSQL is the choice for db management. I can not install MSSQL. There's a db which is created and managed by MSSQL. 
I must not copy the entire data via a script, to my database (because of using real time data)
My only option is, connecting that MSSQL created db with PostgreSQL.

Is it possible? If yes, how? Will there be any relevant limitations for my queries?
Thanks.

Additional details:

I'll make selections, calculations, statistically. 
I won't modify the existing data.

Comment: Why not simply use your preferred SQL mangement tool remotely. They can all be configured to connect to a remote server as long as the server accepts external connections.

Comment: Sidenote: "connecting" two different SQL servers is not really an option -- they all have differences in syntax, features, etc. which don't translate well so there is no "connect PostgreSQL to MSSQL" feature (there may be some bridging software available).

Comment: I tried using remote management. I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: As I said remote management only works if the destination server accepts external connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature, which allows you to connect to a [different database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createserver.html) from within PostgreSQL itself, is called [foreign data wrapper](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html).

[Here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers), there is a list of available foreign data wrappers, but mssql is not included. But ODBC is, so (in theory) if you install [`odbc_fdw`](http://pgxn.org/dist/odbc_fdw/), you can access foreign mssql tables in your PostgreSQL instance.

There is also a [tds_fdw for SQL Server](https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw) which uses FreeTDS for the connection rather than ODBC

Comment: Thanks! At the installation of PostgreSQL, Addon-installation-thing (Cannot remember the name exactly, Stacky-Mtacky thing) shows some additional drivers for it. Will I need them? Your list's elements  have almost the same name with them. Thank you for information.

Comment: Maybe, but i'm not sure. There is an article here (below), how to install it under windows. http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/249-ODBC-Foreign-Data-wrapper-to-query-SQL-Server-on-Window---Part-2.html

Comment: Also note, that `odbc_fdw` is just a beta, and it seems abandoned. But there aren't any other options (yet).